# Json Schema, strictProperties for date-time formatMinimum and formatMaximum

Tags: json, datetime-format, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm having problems with Json Schema when I'm trying to validate date-time value between interval of time [2013-11-17T00:00Z, 2015-11-17T00:00Z] I have this Json Schema:

```
{
  "strictProperties": true ,
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "data": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "exampleDate": {
          "format": "date-time",
          "formatMinimum": "2013-11-17T00:00Z",
          "formatMaximum": "2015-11-17T00:00Z"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "data"
  ]
}
```

And with this json always out is as valid json:

```
{
    "data": {
        "exampleDate": "2010-11-17T00:00:00Z"
    }
}
```

But as you can see, this json is not valid because of the date, it is out of valid range.

I've tested in online tools http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/, http://jsonschemalint.com/draft4/# and with com.github.fge:json-schema-validator:2.2.6. Could someone help me please? Maybe I missing some configuration besides strictProperties? some step?. Thanks in advance =)

Comment: Maybe use regexp https://github.com/rofrol/ajv-regexp-errormessage-example

Answer (score 2):

`formatMinimum` and `formatMaximum` are not in JSON Schema v4 draft. They are proposed features for v5:

https://github.com/json-schema/json-schema/wiki/formatMinimum-(v5-proposal)

However, this library can validate `formatMinimum` and `formatMaximum` using the `v5` option:

https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv#features

Comment: I see, thinking it Java, I though in order to enable v5 options, only I should add strictProperties as true, as says here https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator/wiki/v5:-strictProperties